Open iOS native screen from Flutter application hiding flutter BottomNavigationBar
I have create a Flutter application which has BottomNavigationBar.
Suppose this bottom bar has 3 BottomNavigationBarItem.
2 of them flutter screen but 3rd screen I want to launch as iOS native screen.
I can do by passing the the method channel on iOS native code to launch ViewController.
But iOS native screen hiding flutter bottom tab bar.
I want it should place under the bottom bar so that I can switch in between all other tabs.
Flutter Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: BottomNavigationBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavigationBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<BottomNavigationBarExample> createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationBarExampleState();
}

class _BottomNavigationBarExampleState
    extends State<BottomNavigationBarExample> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    BusinessClass(),
    
    MoreClass()
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(

        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed, // This is all you need!
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),         
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            label: 'More',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MoreClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoreClass({super.key});

  @override
  State<MoreClass> createState() => _MoreClassState();
}

class _MoreClassState extends State<MoreClass> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.example.flutter_ios_channel');

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    openNativeScreen();
    super.initState();
  }

  void openNativeScreen() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('openNativeScreen');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error opening native screen: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 400,
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}


Now iOS Native Code in AppDelegate

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

      let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
      let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.flutter_ios_channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

          channel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            // Handle method calls from Flutter here
            if call.method == "openNativeScreen" {
              // Replace with code to open your native iOS screen

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewC") as! MyViewController

                self.window.rootViewController = viewController
                self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
                
              result(nil) // Optional: Sending a result back to Flutter
            } else {
              result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            }
          })

      
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)      
  }



You need to embed the native screen within the Flutter app rather than replacing the root view controller. This can be done by using a FlutterViewController and presenting it on top of the current Flutter view.

You need to embed the native screen within the Flutter app rather than replacing the root view controller. This can be done by using a FlutterViewController and presenting it on top of the current Flutter view. You can try this:
override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

      let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
      let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.flutter_ios_channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)

      channel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        if call.method == "openNativeScreen" {
          let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
          let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewC") as! MyViewController

          // Present the view controller modally
          controller.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
          
          result(nil)
        } else {
          result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
      }

      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

Update: Ok, than you can use PlatformView.
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class NativeView extends StatelessWidget {
  const NativeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This is used in the platform side to register the view.
    const String viewType = 'native-view';
    // Pass parameters to the platform side.
    final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};

    return Platform.isIOS
        ? UiKitView(
            viewType: viewType,
            layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            creationParams: creationParams,
            creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
          )
        : Text('This platform is not supported');
  }
}

You need to register platform view right before your app initializes.
void main() {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    // Register the platform view for iOS
    final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};
    // This uses the `uiKitView` for iOS.
    UiKitView(viewType: 'native-view', creationParams: creationParams, creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec());
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Your NativeView class will look like this:
import Flutter
import UIKit

class NativeViewFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory {
    private var messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger

    init(messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger) {
        self.messenger = messenger
        super.init()
    }

    func create(
        withFrame frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?
    ) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        return NativeView(
            frame: frame,
            viewIdentifier: viewId,
            arguments: args,
            binaryMessenger: messenger)
    }
}

class NativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    private var _view: UIView

    init(
        frame: CGRect,
        viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
        arguments args: Any?,
        binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
    ) {
        _view = UIView()
        super.init()
        createNativeView(view: _view)
    }

    func view() -> UIView {
        return _view
    }

    private func createNativeView(view _view: UIView) {
        // Customize your native view here
        _view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Native iOS View"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.frame = _view.bounds
        label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        _view.addSubview(label)
    }
}

And here is your AppDelegate:
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let factory = NativeViewFactory(messenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    registrar(forPlugin: "NativeView")?.register(factory, withId: "native-view")

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


controller.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil) will also open on top of bottombar. You wont see and switch to another tab until dismiss presented native iOS controller.

I've updated the answer. You can check again.

You can see details from here: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/macos/platform-views

The code you shared worked well. I have gone through the host documentation as well.
I really appreciate your effort. Thanks :)
